# Another proof of $\phi (p^r) = (p-1)p^{r-1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

As everybody knows

> $\phi (p^r) = (p-1)p^{r-1}$

where $\phi$ is the Euler's totient function and $p$ is a prime number.
We might see this formula as the cardinality of the set of units of $\mathbb{Z}/p^r \mathbb{Z}$, i.e $\phi(p^r) = \vert (\mathbb{Z}/p^r \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \vert$.

Now, let me call $R= \mathbb{Z}/p^r \mathbb{Z}$. Clearly, in $R$ we have the ideal $J=(p+p^r\mathbb{Z})=p\mathbb{Z}/p^r \mathbb{Z}$ which is nilpotent. Furthermore, we know that $x \in R$ is a unit iff $x+J$ is a unit in $R/J$ (this holds  with general ring $R$ and $J$ nilpotent). Using this fact I want to recover the first equality. Any hints?

My idea is to find something like that

> $\phi (p^r) = \vert (\mathbb{Z}/p^r \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \vert= (p-1) \vert J \vert =(p-1)p^{r-1}$

The first and the last equalities are ok, but what about the middle one?

Comment: $|R/J|=p$ and $R/J$ is the  field $\mathbf F_p$, so $|(R/J)^\times|=p-1$ . Where's the problem?

Comment: Is it true that if $R$ is a ring and $J$ is a nilpotent ideal of $R$ we have $x \in R$ is unit iff $x+J$ is a unit in $R/J$? If this holds I suppose $\vert (R)^{\times} \vert = \vert (R/J)^{\times} \vert$, right?

Comment: For  your first question, the answer is ‘yes’, because a nilpotent ideal is contained in the Jacobson radical of $R$. For your second question, a counterexample is the local ring $\mathbf Z/9\mathbf Z$, which has $6$ units, whereas its residue field  is $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$, which has $2$.

Comment: And how can I use the information "$x \in R$ unit iff $x+J$ unit" in order to prove $\phi(p^r)= (p-1)p^{r-1}$?

Comment: The restriction of the canonical map $R\to R/J$ to $R^\times \to(R/J)^\times$ is surjective, and you can apply the *Shepherds' principle*.

Comment: I've never heard about this principle. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106465/discussion-between-bernard-and-davide-motta).

Answer (score 1):

$\lvert (R/J)^\times\rvert$ is not equal to $(p-1)\lvert J\rvert$, but to $p-1$, period: if anything, it's the cardinaliy of its preimage by the quotient map $x\mapsto x+J$ to have that cardinality. Anyways, call $\pi:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/p^r\Bbb Z$ the map $x\mapsto x+p^r\Bbb Z$. Since the map is surjective, $R/J\cong \Bbb Z/(\pi^{-1}(J))=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$

Comment: Here I am, but now I can't understand how to ricover $\phi(p^r) = (p-1)p^{r-1}$ using the fact "$x$ is a unit iff $x+J$ is a unit" with $x \in R$ and $J$ nilpotent ideal of $R$

Comment: @DavideMotta You are saying that $R^\times=\pi_J^{-1}[(R/J)^\times]$ and thus its cardinality is $\sum_{y\in(R/J)^\times}\lvert\pi_J^{-1}(y)\rvert$. Every $\pi_J^{-1}(y)$ is in bijection with $J$.